# print a pyramid with hash blocks

Tags: python

Im stuck with my code. I have to build a pyramid with hash blocks the first row has to start with 2 hash blocks. Every row beneath + 1. How do I implement this program

```
height = input("What height should the pyramid be?")
height = int(height)

while height > 23 :
    height = input("What height should the pyramid be?")
    height = int(height)

for i in range(0, height):
    print("#" * height)

print()
```

Comment: What's the point of while loop?

Comment: 100% sure this is a duplicate. However, why do you always print 5 times "#", you also need a double loop to achieve this

Comment: What the right loop than?

Comment: @matszwecja first I had to program a full square. Thats why the while loop and the integer 23 or less is valid

Comment: Change your print to include your iteration number, not the full height.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of thinking, I found your code. This will not create a triangle or any of the sort but it will create a proper pyramid:

```
height = int(height)

while height > 23:
    height = input("What height should the pyramid be?")
    height = int(height)
c = height

for j in range(height):
    for i in range(j):
        print("#", end="    ")
    height -= 1
    print()
    for h in range(c):
        print("  ", end="")
    c -= 1
```

Here what I have done is, first get the number of spaces needed to enter in the start of the line. Then it will enter the number of hashes required for the pyramid and it will repeat this until the final pyramid is made. But just be careful, you have to enter one number plus the number of the pyramid rows you want. Otherwise it will create a pyramid of the number -1. So you can change the code in the for loop by doing `height+1` or you could just leave it like that.

Comment: i copied your code, is not working

Comment: What is it showing?

Answer (score -1):

```
height = input("What height should the pyramid be: ")
height = int(height)

for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0,i):
        print("#",end =" ")
    print()
```

This is the right loop.

output:

```
What height should the pyramid be: 9
# 
# # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # #
```

EDIT FOR PYRAMID NOT A TRIANGLE

```
rows = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))

k = 0

for i in range(1, rows+1):
    for space in range(1, (rows-i)+1):
        print(end="  ")
   
    while k!=(2*i-1):
        print("* ", end="")
        k += 1
   
    k = 0
    print()
```

Comment: There is no need for a double loop.

Comment: @matszwecja I do believe you are right, Although I think I made a mistake alltoghether. since OP asked for a pyramid not a triangle.

Comment: I mean, pyramid is a 3D thing and usually involves huge blocks of stone, so I guess we could use a definition of a pyramid according to OP.

Comment: It's still much more complicated than it needs to be. `for i in range(1, height):
    print(" ".join(["#"] * i))` will do the trick. `print("#"*i)` if you don't need spaces.